# Azure cognitive search suggestion ignoring word order

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Let say in my index I have this values :

```
Clint Eastwood
Jamie Lee Curtis
```

I have this code simple code

```cs
public void Search(string indexName, string suggester, string name)
{
    var searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), indexName , new AzureKeyCredential(adminApiKey));
    
    var so = new SuggestOptions();
    var sugg = searchClient.Suggest<Request>(name, suggester, so);
}
```

Doing the following search I have this result

```
Working examples:

name = clin
Suggetsion is Clint Eastwood

name = east
Suggestion is Clint Eastwood

name = clint eas
Suggestion is Clint Eastwood
```

```
Not working examples

name = eastwood cl
no suggestion

name = jamie curtis
no suggestions
```

Is there a way to have azure search not too strict in order to have suggestions for both not working examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common use case for autocomplete. My solution is to do token rotation on the content before submitting it to the index. You would then base your suggestions on the Rotated version instead of the Name.

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Clint Eastwood",
        "Rotated": ["Clint Eastwood", "Eastwood Clint"]
    },
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Jamie Lee Curtis",
        "Rotated": ["Jamie Lee Curtis", "Lee Curtis Jamie", "Curtis Jamie Lee"]
    }
]
```

}

I usually rotate the tokens left until like the above. Note that this will not solve your requirement of getting a suggestion for an input of *jamie curtis*. But, you can resolve that by producing additional iterations of the tokens.